# SQL "group by" on multiple fields inflates total result count?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to get the total number of records that exist, that have a timestamp of between today and one week. I need these records in buckets filtered by timestamp and by an additional column `event_type`.

E.g. if these are my records

```
id    timestamp    event_type

1     2024-01-31   signup
2     2024-02-10   login
3     2024-02-11   login
4     2024-02-12   logout
5     2024-02-14   signup
6     2024-02-14   signup
7     2024-02-15   login
```

I want a query that produces this:

```
count    timestamp    event_type
3        2024-02-15   login
1        2024-02-15   logout
2        2024-02-15   signup
```

Because as of today `2024-02-15`, in the past week there were 3 `login` events, 1 `logout` event, and 2 `signup` events. The `signup` event on `2024-01-31` should not be considered.

Initially I wrote this query to just get the counts bucketed only by timestamp:

```
select count(id) from (
    select * from my_table where timestamp > dateadd(days, -7, getdate()) and timestamp < getdate())
)
```

But this result was much higher than the correct value I observed from manually counting the records.

This more complicated query was correct:

```
with cumulative_counts as
    select top 10 timestamp, sum(records) over (order by timestamp rows between 7 preceding and 0 preceding) as count
    from (select timestamp, count(id) as records
        from event_table
        where row_num = 1
        group by timestamp
        order by timestamp asc
    )
)
select * from cumulative_counts where timestamp = getdate()
```

The first and last lines are necessary because without, the query returns a cumulative sum of the past seven days, *for each day* represented in the database, e.g. (with the same example records as above)

```
count    timestamp
6        2024-02-15
5        2024-02-14
3        2024-02-12
2        2024-02-11
1        2024-02-10
1        2024-01-31
```

Now I want my query to also show buckets for `event_type`. I adapted the above query to:

```
with cumulative_counts as
    select top 10 timestamp, sum(records) over (order by timestamp rows between 7 preceding and 0 preceding) as count, event_type
    from (select timestamp, count(id), event_type as records
        from event_table
        where row_num = 1
        group by timestamp, event_type
        order by timestamp asc
    )
)
select * from cumulative_counts where timestamp = getdate()
```

But the counts for each bucket are incorrect - they are higher than than the actual counts by about 50%.

Comment: This `select top 10` is not valid SQL syntax for PostgreSQL and results in a syntax error. What database are you using?

Comment: Redshift, I tagged it with Postgres instead because Redshift is based on Postgres and my question was about this query, not the Redshift service

Answer (score 0):

Mysql has no get_date and dateadd, so i corrected that.

As you see, when you want the last date you need to grab it in a subquery or doe a Cross join.

And you need only to `GROUP BY` by the event_tyoe

```
select 
  COUNT(*),
  (SELECT MAX(`timestamp`) FROM my_table where timestamp >  current_date() - INTERVAL 7 DAY  and timestamp < current_date()) as LAST_Date,
  `event_type`
  from my_table 
  where timestamp >  current_date() - INTERVAL 7 DAY  and timestamp < current_date()
GROUP BY `event_type`
```

| COUNT(*) | LAST_Date | event_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2024-02-15 | login |
| 1 | 2024-02-15 | logout |
| 2 | 2024-02-15 | signup |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ra7HApMo)

## In postgres this would be

```
select 
  COUNT(*),
  (SELECT DATE(MAX("timestamp")) FROM my_table where "timestamp" >  current_date - INTERVAL '7 DAY'  and "timestamp" < current_date) as LAST_Date,
  event_type
  from my_table 
  where timestamp >  current_date - INTERVAL '7 DAY'  and timestamp < current_date
GROUP BY event_type
```

| count | last_date | event_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2024-02-15 | login |
| 1 | 2024-02-15 | logout |
| 2 | 2024-02-15 | signup |

> ```
> SELECT 3
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sO5WMcpG)

#For Redshift

it would looks like

```
select 
  COUNT(*),
  (SELECT TRUNC(MAX("timestamp")) FROM my_table where "timestamp" >  current_date - INTERVAL '7 DAY'  and "timestamp" < current_date) as LAST_Date,
  event_type
  from my_table 
  where timestamp >  current_date - INTERVAL '7 DAY'  and timestamp < current_date
GROUP BY event_type
```

Comment: This won't work in PostgreSQL nor Redshift, better to remove this one

Comment: he should have told me that he chnaged the tags.

Comment: This still gives me the inflated bucket counts, like the last query in the body of my question

Comment: that is impossible, please show the result iof the queryabouve with the example data, that prodzce tzhe error, even when  i remove the subquery i bget he rightbresults, so you haven't presenred the cporrect data that produces the wrong number, or you have other prpblems